# Android: Button Creation in Row

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

Its create dynamic button in a single row

```
 final LinearLayout layoutshape = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearshape);
  a = new Button[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      a[i] = new Button(this);
      a[i].setText(""+i);
      a[i].setId(i);
      a[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      a[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
     layoutshape.addView(a[i]);
    }
```

but I wanna make this to be split in to three rows. 
 Eg: If I've 30 buttons then its should be displayed in 10 button in 1st row then next
10 in second row and 10 in third row

o/p buttons as to be:

b1 b2 b3 b4 b5

b6 b7 b8 b9 b10

b11 b12 b13 b14 b15

Comment: try the gridview for your case.

Comment: any other possibilities in linear?

Comment: Or you can you tablelayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all set orientation for your main layout(layoutshape) to vertical.

```
for (int i = 0; i < i/10; i++) {

LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
```

set orientation for row to horizontal.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

  a[i] = new Button(this);
  a[i].setText(""+i);
  a[i].setId(i);
  a[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  a[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
 row.addView(a[i]);
}
layoutshape.addView(row);
}
```

Comment: @Mj its creates same buttons thrice in a 3rows

Comment: @arshad You are right second loop should be for(i=0;i<10;i++) but this is just a example code.

Answer (score 1):

You will need at least `n` `LinearLayout` where `n` is your number of rows. If you really want to use a `LinearLayout` then add your buttons using the following `LayoutParams`:

`new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1/numButtonsInRow);`

`1/numButtonsInRow` is the weight of the button. For instance if you have 10 buttons in a row, each button will have a weight of `0.1`. If your Layout is horizontal, set its `width` to 0, if it is vertical set its `height` to 0.

In your case, you probably should use a `GridLayout` or `TableLayout` though.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 LinearLayouts in the "layoutshape" LinearLayout with orientation as vertical.
And then add the buttons to the inner linear layouts.

Comment: yeah! had to do with. but looking for any otherways else need to create 3 layouts

Answer (score 0):

30 buttons look like a keyboard:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html
and the keyboard may be created via an xml (see the SoftKeyboard example in SDK, the samples/android-10/SoftKeyboard subdirectory).

If you really need buttons in 3 rows, my suggestion is 3 horizontal linear layouts filled in at run-time. But please note that the screen sizes vary, and what is good on a phone may look ugly on a tablet.